# Replacing binary vector with other binary values using min and max in R

Tags: r, replace, alternating

I have a following matrix:

```
B = as.POSIXct("2015-06-21") + seq(1,18)
P = c(21.675,21.775,21.675,21.725,21.575,21.525,21.625,21.475,21.375,21.325,21.32,21.475,21.375,21.325,21.425,21.525,21.275,21.325)
A = c(-1,1,-1,1,-1,0,1,-1,0,0,0,1,-1,0,1,0,-1,1)
C = c(rep(0,15),1,0,0)
D = c(0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0)
E = seq(1,18)  

dat = as.data.frame(cbind(P,A,C,D))
rownames(dat) = B
```

The output matrix looks like this:

```
                         P  A C  D  E
2015-06-21 00:00:01 21.675 -1 0  0  1
2015-06-21 00:00:02 21.775  1 0  0  2
2015-06-21 00:00:03 21.675 -1 0  0  3
2015-06-21 00:00:04 21.725  1 0  0  4
2015-06-21 00:00:05 21.575 -1 0  0  5
2015-06-21 00:00:06 21.525  0 0 -1  6
2015-06-21 00:00:07 21.625  1 0  0  7
2015-06-21 00:00:08 21.475 -1 0  0  8
2015-06-21 00:00:09 21.375  0 0 -1  9
2015-06-21 00:00:10 21.325  0 0 -1 10
2015-06-21 00:00:11 21.325  0 0 -1 11
2015-06-21 00:00:12 21.475  1 0  0 12
2015-06-21 00:00:13 21.375 -1 0  0 13
2015-06-21 00:00:14 21.325  0 0 -1 14
2015-06-21 00:00:15 21.425  1 0  0 15
2015-06-21 00:00:16 21.525  0 1  0 16
2015-06-21 00:00:17 21.275 -1 0  0 17
2015-06-21 00:00:18 21.325  1 0  0 18
```

Column A has an alternating -1 and 1s. The goal is to look through column A where there are zeros and to see if I can replace them using C and D.

E column indicates the row number and P column contains price information. A column indicates local min and max points (-1 and 1).

So between row 4 and 7, there is a zero in row 6. 4 and 7 indicate local max points with 21.725 and 21.625.

I want to check whether row 5 is indeed the smallest number between row 4 and 7. Turns out, row 6 has a lower value, 21.525 compare to 21.575 of row 5.

So, I want to replace column A's 5th entry to 0 from -1 and 6th entry to -1 from 0.

I want to go through the matrix with the above logic and have the following outcome in the end:

```
                         P  A C  D  E
2015-06-21 00:00:01 21.675 -1 0  0  1
2015-06-21 00:00:02 21.775  1 0  0  2
2015-06-21 00:00:03 21.675 -1 0  0  3
2015-06-21 00:00:04 21.725  1 0  0  4
2015-06-21 00:00:05 21.575  0 0  0  5
2015-06-21 00:00:06 21.525 -1 0 -1  6
2015-06-21 00:00:07 21.625  1 0  0  7
2015-06-21 00:00:08 21.475  0 0  0  8
2015-06-21 00:00:09 21.375  0 0 -1  9
2015-06-21 00:00:10 21.325 -1 0 -1 10
2015-06-21 00:00:11 21.325  0 0 -1 11
2015-06-21 00:00:12 21.475  1 0  0 12
2015-06-21 00:00:13 21.375  0 0  0 13
2015-06-21 00:00:14 21.325 -1 0 -1 14
2015-06-21 00:00:15 21.425  0 0  0 15
2015-06-21 00:00:16 21.525  1 1  0 16
2015-06-21 00:00:17 21.275 -1 0  0 17
2015-06-21 00:00:18 21.325  1 0  0 18
```

I am having trouble writing and efficient code that does goes through this logic. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are `C` and `D` for?

Comment: Its not necessarily in this example but C and D generated the 0s in A.